# c# creating multiple lists within for statement

Tags: c#

Is there a way I can create multiple lists under a "for" statement, with an incrimental naming system (eg monster1, monster2, monster3). I've flagged it up under **this is where I want an incrimental name** within the code.

The number of lists needed to be generated is defined earlier on and I'm having no issues with that, but I'm getting "error CS0128: A local variable named `...' is already defined in this scope" if I attempt to assign the list name based on a variable with an inbuilt counter to incriment the list names (monsterList in this case).

Is there another way I can do this, so that no matter how many lists I need to be generated, it will create them and name them following this set pattern?

The below code is what I'm looking to have iterate a nuber of times (I'm new, so it's probably horribly inefficient, I'm just trying to get it doing what I want for now!):

```
for (int monstCounter = 2; monstCounter < totalTimes; monstCounter++) 
          {
Console.WriteLine();
string monsterLists = "Monster " + monstCounter;
string monsterList = "monsters"+monstCounter;
Console.WriteLine(monsterLists);
    p = 0;
    foreach (Monster aMonster in monsters)
    {
      if (monsters[p].MonsterName == monsterLists)
      y = p;
      p++;
    }
    y = monsters[y].MonsterPopu;

    //Create a list of individuals.
    List<MonsterStatistics> **This is where I want an incrimental name** = new List<MonsterStatistics>();
      totalTimes1 = y;
      counter1 = 1;
        for (int b=0; b < totalTimes1; b++) 
          {

    // Add monsters to the list.
      monsterList.Add(new MonsterStatistics() {oldAge = rndNum.Next(1,100), name = "Name"+counter1, coupled = false, genderGen = rndNum.Next(0,2)}); 
    counter1++;
}  

foreach (MonsterStatistics aMonster in monsterList){
          if(aMonster.genderGen == 0)
          aMonster.gender = "Male";
          else if (aMonster.genderGen == 1)
          aMonster.gender = "Female";
          else 
          aMonster.gender = "Genderless";
aMonster.age = rndNum.Next(0,aMonster.oldAge);
Console.WriteLine(aMonster.name + " Age: " + aMonster.age + "/" + aMonster.oldAge + " " + aMonster.gender);
}
}
```

Comment: Why not just create a `Dictionary<string, List<MonsterStatistics>>` and add as many lists to that as you want?

Answer (score 2):

You can't create variables from a string, its not how variables work in C#.

What you cand o is use a Dictionary and assign for each monsters list a unique key (string), something like:

```
Dictionary<string, List<MonsterStatistics>> monstersStatistics = new Dictionary<string, List<MonsterStatistics>>();

// Add a monster (here you can name monster with an incrementing variable)
monstersStatistics.Add("monster1", new List<MonsterStatistics>());
// Then fill the monster's statistics
monstersStatistics["monster1"].Add(new MonsterStatistics() { oldAge = rndNum.Next(1, 100), name = "Name" + counter1, coupled = false, genderGen = rndNum.Next(0, 2) });
```